# Make button perform action using URL without opening new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to start and stop my EC2 instance on AWS using an HTML button and some JavaScript, if necessary.

I do not want the button to navigate to a new page; it should only perform the start/stop action.

Example HTML:

```html
Click Here To Disable QA Servers : 
<BR><BR> 
<form action="https://*************1.amazonaws.com/stop/stop">
    <input type="submit" value="Click Here!" />
</form>
```

Comment: both of those 2 solutions not help me.i dont want to open it in new page,just to run it in the background

Answer (score 0):

you can use (get / post) request jquery like:

html:

```
<div>
    ...
    <button id="btn-start">Click to start</button>
    <button id="btn-stop">Click to stop</button>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#btn-stop').on('click', function (e) {
    $.get( "https://****1.amazonaws.com/stop/stop", function( data ) {
        // Some logic
    });
});

$('#btn-start').on('click', function (e) {
      $.get( "https://****1.amazonaws.com/start/start", function( data ) {
            // Some logic
      });
 });
```

Comment: How can i do it for 2 buttons ? @yoan

Comment: Use id for the buttons and the jquery

Comment: not working @yoan when i do that : $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.get("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
}); its work for 1 button

Comment: weird for me is working fine, please check the code again ;)

Comment: just copy,change the url,and paste ,,nothing.../:

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean once you click submit you don't want the page to reload? If so you can use `e.preventDefault();`. Check out the fiddle. Sorry if I misunderstood the question.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('No page reload.');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zouLcq9v/